# Python: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Service Industries Journal'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I just started to code with Python.

I am doing some analysis on a database of papers extracted from the Scopus database. I downloaded the database in .csv and then performed some analyses and filtering on it. After the initial analyses I saved the file in .xlsx which is the current format of the database.
I am trying to obtain a graph showing  how many times a journal is present in the database.
I have extracted the values using the `value_counts()` command and then I have stored these data into a table with two columns (`Journal` and `Count`):

```
journals_count = data['Source_title'].value_counts().reset_index()
journals_count.columns = ['Journal', 'Count']

                                          Journal Count
0     IEEE Transactions on Industrial Informatics 40
1                Expert Systems with Applications 37
2                                  Applied Energy 20
3   International Journal of Production Economics 13
4                            Energy and Buildings 11
5                            Information Sciences 11
6 International Journal of Information Management 10
7                        Decision Support Systems 9
8 International Journal of Advanced Manufacturing 9 
9    International Journal of Production Research 8
10       European Journal of Operational Research 7
```

Now I would like to create a bar chart from this table with the `Journal` name on the x-axis and the `Count` value on the y-axis using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot(journals_count['Journal'], journals_count['Count'])
```

The problem is that I obtain the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Service Industries Journal'
```

`'Service Industries Journal'` is the last journal with the `Count` value equal to 1.

How could I plot this into Python?

Comment: If you are working with pandas then you can do it directly from pandas' methods; you can have a look how to do it in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should enumerate the `String` values in `journals_count['Journal']` into `[1, 2, 3, ...]`. After that map those values to your `journals_count['Journal']` with `xticks`.

```
x = np.arange(len(journals_count['Journal']))
plt.xticks(x, journals_count['Journal'])
plt.plot(x, journals_count['Count'])
plt.show()
```